# Do multiple lantern archon's Aura of Menace debuffs stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stacking, aura

I summoned six [lantern archons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/archon/lantern-archon/). They each have the ability Aura of Menace with a save DC of 13:

> Aura of Menace (Su) A righteous aura surrounds archons that fight or get angry. Any hostile creature within a 20-foot radius of an archon must succeed on a Will save to resist its effects. The save DC varies with the type of archon, is Charisma-based, and includes a +2 racial bonus. Those who fail take a –2 penalty on attacks, AC, and saves for 24 hours or until they successfully hit the archon that generated the aura. A creature that has resisted or broken the effect cannot be affected again by the same archon’s aura for 24 hours.

The debuff seems to be untyped. If the enemy fails his save vs all six auras, does he suffer -12 to attacks, AC, and saves?

Answer (score 2):

## No, they don’t stack

Penalties are untyped, and penalties from the same source don’t stack. Multiple *auras of menace* are still penalties coming from *aura of menace*, and do not stack with one another.

Beyond that, *aura of menace* is **very** potent ability. Having a gang of lantern archons nuke the party’s saving throws will quickly turn just about any encounter into an impossible deathtrap. Consider: a *good save* increases by +1 every *two* levels. A −2 penalty represents reducing your saving throws by *four levels’ worth*. At minimum. For poor saving throws, it’s *six*. How many things can survive the attacks of things four or six levels higher than they are? Not many. If you are going to increase that to eight or twelve or more, the players might as well not even bother trying.

## They do, however, overlap

Effects that don’t stack still exist. If you succeed on the saving throw against one *aura of menace*, you still are subject to the others. If you fail saving throws against multiple *auras of menace*, you can break one by attacking the lantern archon producing it, but you are still subject to the penalties from the other *aura(s) of menace* that you failed the saving throw for. So multiple lantern archons can still be a large benefit, simply because they make it so much harder for enemies to protect themselves from the *aura of menace*.

Comment: I don't think the same aura from multiple enemies is same source. I'll look into it, but some reference to 'sources' being anything with the same name, not from the same enemy would improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, they stack

Penalties are often untyped, and so usually stack.  Each archon's aura is separate and requires a separate save, and any enemies failing all six saves and remaining within the area of every aura would consequently take a -12 penalty to AC and on attack rolls and saving throws, at least until they had hit one of the menacing archons or 24 hours had passed.